# Play framework if else case Not working

Tags: scala, playframework

Play framework if else case is not working here

If  userprofile.useraccountid, useraccount.id have the same value  then not views that id user on view page

my code in the view..

```
@(userprofiles: List[UserProfile],myFriend:models.MyFriend,userprofile:models.UserProfile,useraccount:models.UserAccount)
 @helper.form(action = routes.Application.createMyFriend) {
    <br/><br/><br/>
    @for(userprofile <- userprofiles){
        @if(userprofile.useraccountid != useraccount.id) {
            <img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/img2.png")" width="200" height="200" />
            <br>
            <h5>@userprofile.name</h5>
            <h5>@userprofile.useraccountid</h5>=<h5>@useraccount.id</h5>
            <h6>@userprofile.gender</h6>
            <h6>@userprofile.date_of_birth</h6>
            <div class="actions">
                <input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="+1 Add As Friend" title="Send Friend Request">
            </div>
            <br/>
        }
    } 
}
```

when checking the condition the database values are views in the view page and

```
@if(userprofile.useraccountid != useraccount.id)
```

if change the condition to

```
 @if(userprofile.useraccountid == useraccount.id)
```

Nothing will in the view page.

In this code when run the program the code section

```
 <h5>@userprofile.useraccountid</h5>=<h5>@useraccount.id</h5>
```

The id's are same here , and that show in the view  then the idea is not false.. for example 15=15.

Here the 2 id are same but the checking in the if case is not work properly... or the coding is not right.

Edit
This is in application

```
 def listMyFriend = Action { implicit request =>
    var cid=request.session.get("userId")
    println("aa",cid)
   if (request.session.get("userId") == None) {
      Results.Redirect("/")
    }
   else {
        val userprofiles:UserProfile=null
        val userprofileId = request.session.get("userId").get.toLong//userProfileId
        val userprofile = UserProfile.findUserByAccountId(userprofileId).get
        println(userprofile)
       /*   val myfriendId = request.session.get("myFriendId").get.toLong//myFriendId
        val myfriend = MyFriend.friendidByUserIsAccepted(myfriendId,true)
        println(myfriend)*/
        myFriendForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
        errors => BadRequest(views.html.myFriend(errors, userprofile,myfriend,myfrnd)),
   myFriend => {
          println("errors")
          val myFriendOpt = UserProfile.myFriend(userprofile.id.get)
          println(myFriendOpt)
   myFriendOpt match {
   case None =>
     }
          Results.Redirect("/myFriend")
        })  
        }
    }
```

Comment: what are the types of `useraccount.id` and `userprofile.useraccountid`? Could they be of different types?

Comment: No.. they are Long and and they are in different data tables

Comment: am sure the 2 id's are Long

Comment: Can you show us the classes of `userprofile` and `useraccount` and how you pass these to your view? Besides that, does: `a.toLong.equals(b.toLong)` work (with `a` and `b` your respective variables)?

Comment: Oh, you have shadowing issues in your code: `userprofile` is both defined as a parameter of your template and as the variable you get out of the `for` comprehension. Try renaming one of the two and sort out which one you want to refer to in your `if`.

Comment: you can post it as a answer and i want to accept it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have shadowing issues in your code: `userprofile` is both defined as a parameter of your template and as the variable you get out of the `for` comprehension.

```
@(userprofiles: List[UserProfile],myFriend:models.MyFriend,userprofile:models.UserProfile,useraccount:models.UserAccount)
                                                    here ---^
 @helper.form(action = routes.Application.createMyFriend) {
    <br/><br/><br/>
    @for(userprofile <- userprofiles){
and here ---^
```

Try renaming one of the two and sort out which one you want to refer to in your `if`.

Comment: I change that into 
@helper.form(action = routes.Application.createMyFriend) {
<br/><br/><br/>
@for(userprfile <- userprofiles){
@if(userprofile.useraccountid != useraccount.id) {
<img src="@routes.Assets.at("images/img2.png")" width="200" height="200" />
<br><h5>@userprfile.name</h5>@userprfile.useraccountid----@userprfile.id
<h6>@userprfile.gender</h6>
<h6>@userprfile.date_of_birth</h6>
<div class="actions">
<input type="submit" class="btn primary" value="+1 Add As Friend" title="Send Friend Request"></div>
<br/>
}
} 
}  And
userprofile:models.UserProfile as the parameter

Comment: where do you get the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: [NullPointerException: null] 
@if(userprofile.useraccountid != useraccount.id) {
here

Comment: well, either your parameter `userprofile: UserProfile` or `useraccount: UserAccount` is null.